# angular 2 ng-bootstrap type ahead component - Can't bind to 'ngModel'

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the type-ahead http example to my project (ng-bootstrap). I have simply copied over the typeahead-http html and typescript file. I then changed my app.module.ts to include the type ahead files :

```
import { WikipediaService } from './components/TypeAhead/typeahead-http';
import { NgbdTypeaheadHttp } from './components/TypeAhead/typeahead-http';
```

I've added NgbdTypeaheadHttp to the list of declarations and WikipediaService to the providers but i keep getting the following error :

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("div class="form-group" [class.has-danger]="searchFailed">
][(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="Wikipedia search" />

Things i've checked/tried

- Bootstrap css has been added
- My app.module has import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
- I've tried adding FormControl, etc from @angular/forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you imported forms module in your app.module and declared it in imports array?

Comment: I was adding the ReactiveFormsModule instead of the FormsModule